# Improving slow MySQL select query or improving DB structure?

Tags: mysql, select, relational-database

I am working on a hoby project that contains a module that crawls web pages for information. Database management is not my strongest side and I have now reach a point where I need help. I have set up 10 crawlers that simultanously crawls pages from a table at soonest 3 minutes after publishing and never later than 60 days after publishing (these time intervals has to do with how the crawled system works). What I have is three tables:

1. A page content table that contains all the information from the crawled pages as well as some meta data of those pages (like publishing dates that are updated from an external source)

   - Table name: pages
   - Columns: id (PK), url, publishingDate, name, description, category...
   - Size: about 500K of rows
2. A table of pages in need of crawling. Rows in this table are added by an external system but removed when a crawler has completed crawling of a page in this table.

   - Table name: needsCrawling
   - Column: pageId (FK of pages)
   - Size: at most 50K
3. A crawler task table that contains a set of pages that a certin crawler should crawl:

   - Table name: crawlerTaskList
   - Columns: id (PK), crawlerId (FK of a table called crawlers), pageId (FK of pages)
   - Size: at most 1K rows (10 crawlers and each crawler never has more than 100 pages in it's task list)

The thought behind this is that table 1 (pages) is used to fetch publishingDates and then used for storing the fetched crawl result. Table number 2 is used for "marking" what pages should be crawled and then remove the "mark" after they have been crawled (the publishing date must still be checked since a page might be in need of crawling when, but not before, the publishing date criteria has been met). Table 3 (crawlerTaskList) is used mainly to prevent crawlers from crawling the same pages.

The query I initially used to fetch url's for the crawlers looked like this:

```
SELECT id, url
FROM pages
WHERE publishingDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 minute
  AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) < publishingDate
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT pageId FROM crawlerTaskList)
  AND id IN (SELECT pageId FROM needsCrawling)
ORDER BY publishingDate
```

It has worked fine until the pages table reached about 300K. Now I have reached a point where the query takes about 40 seconds and it starts to be unsustainable. I have tried to re-write the query (e.g. use JOINs instead of the id IN/ id NOT IN) but without any improvement so I am in desperate need of suggestions. Maybe I must add an index or something else fancy that is out of my knowledge. Thanks anyone that takes his/her time to read all this and sorry for the LONG post!

Comment: I did not read all your post but you should consider doing joins instead of sub select with `IN`.

Comment: Yes, I know I should have tried to make it shorter but didn't know what part to leave out. In the last paragraph I write that I have tried joins instead but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In earlier versions of MySQL `in` with a subquery was particularly poorly optimized.  Simply moving it to a join can improve performance:

```
SELECT id, url
FROM pages join
     (select distinct pageid from needsCrawling) nc
     on pages.id = nc.pageid left outer join
     (select distinct pageid from crawlerTaskList) ctl
     on pages.id = clt.pageid
WHERE publishingDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 minute
  AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) < publishingDate
  AND id ctl.pageid is null
ORDER BY publishingDate;
```

Note:  the `distinct` is only there in the event that `pageid` could be duplicated in either table.  You should remove it if you know that it is not duplicated.  Also, indexes on `needsCrawling(pageid)` and `crawlerTaskList(pageId)` would help improve performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The previous join I tried must have been incorrect. This query combined with the two indexes improved the query time by about 35 seconds. The query is not run often so 6-7 seconds is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `EXPLAIN` (or explain extended) before `select`, this should give you the informations you need and give some clues,where to add indexes to speed query up.

Answer (score -1):

Every modern database will optimize your query to an extremely good degree, so you can write pretty much anything you want and the DB will optimize it.

So you basically have two options:
Add indexes to your tables or improve your db (I would highly recommend the second)

Comment: . . Based on your first statement, I wish I lived in your reality.  It is particularly untrue for MySQL, however.

Comment: Ok, thanks! If I first go for the first suggestion (adding indexes), do you have a suggestion of what to index? I feel like I am fumbling in the dark.